# Form focus information or changing tab data on external programs

Tags: c#, .net, tabs

I'm faced with a program that is written externally... it's closed to the outside world and nobody but the developers can edit it and they don't seem to know what tab order even means. I want to create an application that can sort of interface with this program and latch onto the controls of the various forms within it and find a way to restructure the tab order in the program.

Are there any win32 api commands that let you peek in on the internals of a running application or somehow reflect on that application figure out what control within it has active and all the controls on a current form?

What I'm envisioning is a program that lets you look at a windows form in an application that you have no control over, and select the particular controls on the form you're interested in. Say you only want controls a, b, c, x, y, z and none of the other ones... you'd then have your tab orders set to only focus on a, b, c, x, y, z and not any of the other controls on the form. I want to try and accomplish this without having access to any of the code and without resorting to some sort of macro program.

I'm sick and tired of people who write applications that individuals use constantly for data entry and their tab order is completely asinine and they won't change it without charging lots of money.